# Understanding host mounted volume changes in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-build

I've got a monorepo with a `docker-compose.yml` containing:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  alpha:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: projects/alpha/Dockerfile
      target: alpha
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./projects/alpha:/projects/alpha
```

The `Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM python:3.11.3-slim as builder

# Make / set a working directory
WORKDIR /projects/alpha

# Install Poetry and system dependencies
RUN apt update && ... (install necessary apt packages)

# Copy pyproject.toml / poetry.lock
COPY projects/alpha/pyproject.toml projects/alpha/poetry.lock* ./

# Poetry install
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Copy source
COPY projects/alpha ./

# Add a random file to the directory
RUN touch ./RANDO.md

FROM builder as alpha
CMD gunicorn --reload -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:80 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker alpha.asgi:application
```

In the above scenario, `--reload` does what I'd expect - it reloads the workers when I make changes to Python modules on the host machine. If I didn't mount the host directory and instead simply let Docker automatically create a volume, that wouldn't work, because editing files on the host wouldn't result in changes in the container's files. That's all good and well.

If I shell into the container, the `RANDO.md` file I `touch`ed doesn't exist, nor does it in my host directory.

However, if, while I'm shelled into the container, I `touch RANDO.md`, the file is created and visible both inside the container and in my host directory.

What is actually happening (both in the container *and* in my mounted host directory) when the `WORKDIR /projects/alpha` is run during the Docker build?

Comment: Realized I didn't actually answer your question about `WORKDIR`, so I've added that to my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORKDIR changes the working directory in the container of any build actions that follow it, and it makes the directory and its parents if needed. As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir):

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD,
> ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the
> Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if
> it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

It is roughly equivalent to :
`RUN mkdir -p /path/to/work/dir && cd /path/to/work/dir`.

Docker strongly recommends using WORKDIR instead of manually running `cd path` commands to change the working directory as it is easier to read and debug issues.

The problem is that you are copying to and touching files in a location that you are then remapping to a host directory as a mounted volume.

The `COPY` command is executed at build time.  Volumes are mounted when the container starts.  When you mount a local host directory or a volume to a location on the container, you are changing any reference to that location on the container to that mounted location.

In other words, what you are doing is:

1. Your `COPY` steps and `RUN touch ./RANDO.md` are occuring in the local file location of `/projects/alpha` on the container
2. The container starts and the bind mount `./projects/alpha:/projects/alpha` is put place.
3. Now that the container is running, any reference within the container to `/projects/alpha` is now accessing the bind mount and not the local directory.

If you want to see what's happening, try changing your WORKDIR to `/projects/beta`.  You should see the files you copied and the RANDO.md file in `/projects/beta`, and then you'll see the mounted directory in `projects/alpha`.
Or just start the container once without mounting the volume.

Comment: Just realized I didn't actually answer the question of what WORKDIR does, so adding that now.